# vim paste from clipboard in terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

I'm trying to write an insert mode mapping for pasting from the system clipboard.
I have this:

```
imap <c-p> <c-o>:set paste<cr><c-r><c-r>+<c-o>:set nopaste<cr>
```

(Note that this is supposed to work according to [this](http://www.userobsessed.net/tips-and-tricks/2011/05/10/copy-and-paste-in-vim/))

However when invoking the key mapping, it doesn't work, it stops short at the set paste part, so I just end up with paste mode enabled.

But if I do all those keys manually then I get what I want...so what's different when the commands are under a keymap? What am I missing to make this work?

I have also tried this:

```
imap <c-p> <esc>"+gP
```

This throws a slew of errors about gP being an unknown variable, but the same mapping in normal mode works as expected...so what's different with insert mode mappings?

Comment: The author of the cited userobsessed article is not very experienced with Vim. I use `vim` in a terminal all day, have no problems pasting, and don't jump through all those hoops. To paste from the + register while maintaining the original formatting, use `<C-R><C-O>+`. See `:help i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O` for more on this. I don't know what's wrong with your second imap--it works fine for me.

Comment: I did not see this comment until now, that's strange...did you edit? Anyway, thanks, that's how I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to `:set paste` when inserting the clipboard's contents with `i_CTRL-R`. Because of the command, Vim already knows that this is from the clipboard. `:set paste` is for when you paste directly from the terminal (e.g. via the middle mouse button); there, Vim cannot differentiate between characters typed or pasted, and needs this hint.

To avoid auto-indenting, use `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`.

Comment: Yes but I noticed that when I paste code the indentation still gets destroyed without paste mode enabled.

Comment: Then just use the right command: `<C-R><C-O>{register}` :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, but wasn't able to answer my own question for 8 hours :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what's wrong with the first mapping I tried, as I believe it should work, but looking into the vim documentation (specifically :help i_CTRL-R) I came up with a better solution:

```
inoremap <c-p> <c-r><c-o>+
```

From the docs:

> CTRL-R CTRL-O {0-9a-z"%#*+/:.-=}          *i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O*       Insert the
>   contents of a register literally and don't        auto-indent.  Does the
>   same as pasting with the mouse        ||.        Does not replace
>   characters!       The '.' register (last inserted text) is still inserted
>   as        typed.  {not in Vi}

Answer (score 0):

That second imap command should work fine.
As I understand it, it should exit insert mode, paste from one of the system clipboards (+) then leave the cursor after the pasted text.

I suspect you are either running vi not vim or your vim is in compatible mode.
The documentation for ["x]gP `(:help gP)` says "not in vi" so that might be your issue

Comment: I am certainly running vim and it is not in compatible mode.